# Opposite of INNER JOIN with EXIST requirement

Tags: mysql

If inner join requires that a row exists, what's the opposite of it without having to do a sub query of `NOT EXISTS`?

I replaced

```
 AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT
   *
  FROM topic_read_assoc
  WHERE topic_id = topic.id
   AND member_id = ".$this->tru->application->currentMember->getId()."
 )
```

with

```
OUTER JOIN topic_read_assoc ON (
 topic_read_assoc.topic_id = topic.id AND
 member_id = member_id = ".$this->tru->application->currentMember->getId()."
)
```

and it's not producing the same results as the first query (which works)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`OUTER JOIN with a WHERE field IS NULL`

Example:

`SELECT A.name FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.id`

Select those names in A whose id fields exist in B

**Opposite:**

`SELECT A.name FROM A OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.id WHERE B.id IS NULL`

Select those names in A whose id fields **do not** exist in B

Comment: And the exact answer is Left Outer Join

Comment: Ah yes, I was relying on the outer join being a left outer join. But to get only those that do not exist, you still need the null check. You could get the same results with a Right Outer Join as well, but the null check would have to change.

Answer (score -1):

i think select on outer join is slow, because dbms left join first,then right join and delete the repeated rows.So I suggest you to select on the left join,then right join,make a intersect.It is better not operate on any join,because the view doesnt have index.

Comment: You don't know what the DBMS does. It doesn't have to do that.